# How to make a seamless transition between WP7 splashscreen and first page with same splashscreen

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, splash-screen

I'm developing a Windows Phone application. When I launch, the splash screen is shown very shortly, and the `MainPage.xaml` is shown. However, in the MainPage, I setup the camera with the usual code:

```
if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary))
{
    _photoCamera.Initialized += OnCameraInitialized;
    // And other event handling

    viewfinderBrush.SetSource(_photoCamera);
}
```

This is simplified, but it all works. My problem is that this takes a while (mabye 0.5 - 1 seconds, I didn't time it exactly).

So what my user gets is a splashscreen that's so fast, he/she can't see it; and a first page that takes just that tiny fraction to experience it as slightly laggy/slow.

I'd like to change it. Have the splashscreen show until everything is initialized. This has the added benefit of branding for me, and a nice experience for the user.

I've tried this:

- Add my splashscreen as image into my MainPage, on top of everything else and hide it when everything is initialized
- Add my splashscreen in a popup on my MainPage, and hide the popup when everything is initialized (found that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/17/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications.aspx))

This 'works', but I can see a black flash between the splashscreen and my image/popup. Is there a way to make this transition seamless? Or is this fairly normal behavior in WP7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option should work - but understand that in one trip through a UI-thread method, the UI doesn't actually update until all the code is executed. So break it up into pieces.

1) Load your MainPage.xaml, which has the splash image filling the screen by default

2) Add an event handler for both OnNavigatedTo and LayoutUpdated. When OnNavigatedTo is hit, set a flag to true. In LayoutUpdated, check for that flag to be true, set the flag to false, then run a Dispatcher.Invoke() call on the method you described above.

3) Remove the image or set it to collapsed after that method is completed.